# Remote Desktop Connection session hangs randomly over HDMI display

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, hdmi

At random times,  when I connect my laptop to my monitor via HDMI and open my remote desktop session on the monitor while running other things on the laptop, the remote desktop session hangs and I wouldn't be able to access the remote PC until I restart it forcefully. Is it due to the HDMI connection, display aspect, or connection problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.